# postgres update query not works from Metabase

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I'm using the open source Metabase version, and I was able to connect my PostgreSQL databases correctly.

but when im trying to run a update query from metabase its throws below error.

```
ERROR: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction
```

but when I execute same query from terminal and pgAdmin its worked and updated the rows as well.

so i thought the issue is the connection between metabase and PostgreSQL,

then i tried to change the connection propertes as below way.
[image]

I have tried below arguments as well.

- default_transaction_read_only=off
- readonlymode=ignore
- readonlymode=off

but im still geting the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metabase isn't geared toward modifying any data in the source databases it knows about.

Seemingly as a way to enforce this usage pattern, Metabase's developers are using the `setReadOnly` method when creating JDBC connection objects which is likely overriding any driver-level properties you've set. (This happens in the file `src/metabase/driver/sql_jdbc/execute.clj` in the Metabase codebase.) You could attempt to change this by compiling your own custom version of Metabase, but you might achieve some unexpected results.

Update: the [Actions feature](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/actions/start) released in Metabase 46 now supports creating, updating, and deleting rows in tables.